# iPhone SDK - How to Tell if a Text Field Has Text?

Tags: iphone

Sorry for the simple question but I feel like there's a smarter way to do this:

```
if ([txtFldTo.text length]>0){ 
    //do something
}
else {
    //do something else
}
```

where txtFldTo is an IBOutlet UITextField connected to a text field on the interface.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this should suffice.

if([[textfield text] length] > 0)

Comment: That was my guess, I just thought there was a better way; e.g., !=@"", or or simply not textfield.text.

Answer (score 3):

You're doing it right.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (![[textfield text] isEqualToString:@""]) {

}
```

or

```
if ([[textfield text] length] != 0) {

}
```